Special Vector Fields Preserving Harmonic Spinors
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $(\Sigma,\mathrm{cl}^g,h,\nabla^h)$ be a Hermitian Dirac bundle and $D$ its Dirac operator. Let $\psi$ be a harmonic spinor, i.e.
$D\psi=\mathrm{cl}^g\circ\nabla^h\psi=0$ and $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ a vector field on $M$.
Then one can ask the following natural question: When is $\nabla_X\psi$ or $\mathrm{cl}^g(X)\psi$ harmonic?
By using that $\nabla^h$ is a $CL(TM,g)$-module connection we can rewrite these two equations
$D\nabla_X\psi=-\mathrm{cl}^g\circ (\iota_X F_{\nabla^h}+\nabla^h_{\mathcal{L}_X})\psi=-\sum_i(\mathrm{cl}^g(e_i)F_{\nabla^h}(X,e_i)+\nabla^h_{\mathcal{L}_{X}e_i})\psi=0$
$D\mathrm{cl}^g(X)\psi=(\mathrm{cl}^g\circ\mathrm{cl}^g(\nabla^gX)+\nabla^h_X)\psi=(\sum_i\mathrm{cl}^g(e_i)\mathrm{cl}^g(\nabla^g_{e_i}X)+\nabla^h_X)\psi=0$
Can we say anything about $X$? Does it vanish if $M$ is compact and possibly scalar-flat? (I think i can prove the second statement using the Weitzenbock formula
$D^2=(\nabla^h)^*\nabla^h+\frac{1}{4}scal_g+\mathrm{cl}^g(F^{tw.}_{\nabla^h})$
and the fact that the Clifford multipication with the twisting curvature $F^{tw.}_{\nabla^h}=F_{\nabla^h}-\rho(R^g)$ and the Clifford multiplication with $X$ commute. Here $[\rho(R^g(X,Y)),\mathrm{cl}^g(Z)]=\mathrm{cl}^g(R^g(X,Y)Z)$)
